# Keeping track of member arguments of derived class

Tags: c++, overloading, wrapper, new-operator

Let's say I have a library with a virtual class called `INode`. The user of the library is suposed to use `INode` for creation of multiple concrete nodes (e.g. single `ConcreteNode`) with any kind of functionality specialized by the user.

Right now, if inside of any `ConcreteNode` I want to declare a "special" scalar argument, I call `arguments.scalar.add(0)` method, witch creates me a new entry inside an intern vector of scalar values (is it practically `std::vector<double>`) and initiates it with an `id = 0`. Besides the named vector of doubles called `scalar` I also prepared containers with vectors (`arguments.vector.`) and matrices (`argument.matrix.`) to be called in the same way as shown.

All of this is motivated with the thought, that I want to keep track of the state (e.g. `bool is_set;`) for all arguments of `ConcreteNode`. This must happen "internally", such that the creator of `ConcreteNode` does not need to keep track of these arguments manually via creation of such state variables.

My current approach works, but it is limited to predefined containers (scalar, vector, matrix). Is the library used wanted to use some other data type, he must add a new entry inside `INode`class. Second issue is, that if I create `ConcreteNode` witch is only using a single scalar argument, containers for vectors and matrices are also created. This leads to dead code, unnecessary memory usage and the most important part is that I am making requests on all containers like `bool arguments.are_set();` witch checks through all of the arguments, even if there are none of them created for vector and matrix.

I am searching for a better solution. One thought was, what if I will overload `new` operator inside `INode` class, such that every newly created argument of any type inside derived class is internally registered in the way that is it is given few state arguments and few standard functions set/get. 
Then the code might be way flexible and probably look like this:

```
struct ConcreteNode : INode
{
ConcreteNode() { bool* arg = new bool; }
void foo() override { /* ... use arg ... */ };
}
```

On this point I ask myself if this boilerplate with `new` is really necessary. Couldn't I just create a wrapper around the `new` operator to make it look like normal member initialization like `bool arg;`. Or maybe I am missing some clever trick in cpp witch allows me keep track of created members directly.

I hope I did the point of my thoughts clear and you could help me to go further with them.

EDIT1: Also I was thinking about making some template structures witch might behave like.

```
struct ConcreteNode : INode
{
ConcreteNode()
{  arguments.add<bool>("arg");
   arguments.set<bool>("arg") = true; }
void foo() override { /* ... bool b = arguments.get<bool>("arg"); ... */ };
}
```

EDIT2: Right now, for the current state of code I declare new arguments inside derived class like this:

```
struct ConcreteNode : INode
{
ConcreteNode(double a, std::vector<double> b)
{  arguments.add.scalar(0);
   arguments.add.vector(1);

   arguments.set.scalar(0) = a;
   arguments.set.vector(1) = b;
 }
void foo() override 
{ 
   double c = arguments.get.scalar(0);
   std::vector<double> d = arguments.get.vector(1);
   // ...
};
}
```

Comment: Two things stand out to me: First is that you define `arg` as a *local* variable inside the constructor. The second is that there's no need for pointers or `new` at all. Why not a simple non-pointer `bool` member variable?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ye, you are right, this example does not show my intent. I did it this way because as I am using my current state of the code, I define new arguments inside the constructor. I will add an example of current code in EDIT2.

Comment: There is no code per object. Code is only "dead code" if nothing calls it ever. Empty containers use very little memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The simple non-pointer `bool` doesn't give me opportunity to make some operations on it from base class `INode`. Overloaded `new` might do so.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to pass strings as arg names? The way I'd prefer to solve it is a 3-level hierarchy: `class INode` defining common interface, `template<typename Args... args> class INodeImpl : public INode` defining generic member handling, `class ConcreteNode : public INodeImpl<double, std::vector<double>` with member-specific handling and named getters for the args. Either that, or CRTP middleman class.